# Reading Arabic characters using MQ connection

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am reading xml data using MQ connection that contains some arabic characters. But in the log4j log file it shows some junk characters like Ø²Ù?Ø§Ø¯ Ø³Ø¹Ù?Ø¯ Ø£Ø­Ù. Also the same junk values are used in further usage of same program. Please help to read the proper arabic characters values and to display the same chars in log4j file.

Mq configuration details are,
  MQEnvironment.channel=SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN
  MQEnvironment.CCSID=1208

My concern is not exactly viewing arabic characters in log. Actually I am not sure whether I am reading right arabic characters or not using MQ code.

Given below the code used to read from host & write xml data in log file.

```
public boolean SendReceiveData (String sWriteQueName, String sReadQueName, String sRequestMessage, int iWaitInterval, int iExpiryInterval ){
        mqLogger.info(sessionId+"MQConnection->SendReceiveData() Called");
        int iQueOpenOptions;                                 
        int iMessageLength;
        int iCounter;

    try
       {
          //Open the write queue and put the message
          iQueOpenOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;      
          messageInputQueue = queueManager.accessQueue(sWriteQueName, iQueOpenOptions);
          mqLogger.debug(sessionId+"Opened the queue - " + sWriteQueName);

          MQPutMessageOptions putMessageObject = new MQPutMessageOptions();
          MQMessage mqSendMessage = new MQMessage();

          mqSendMessage.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
          mqSendMessage.expiry = iExpiryInterval;
          mqSendMessage.write(sRequestMessage.getBytes());
          mqSendMessage.originalLength = sRequestMessage.length();
          mqSendMessage.replyToQueueName = sReadQueName;
          mqSendMessage.characterSet = 1208;

          messageInputQueue.put(mqSendMessage,putMessageObject);
          mqLogger.info(sessionId+"Message put on the queue - " + sWriteQueName);

          messageInputQueue.close();
          mqLogger.debug(sessionId+"Closed the queue - " + sWriteQueName);


          //Open the read queue and get the message
          iQueOpenOptions = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT;
          messageOutputQueue = queueManager.accessQueue(sReadQueName, iQueOpenOptions);
          mqLogger.debug(sessionId+"Opened the queue - " + sReadQueName);

          MQGetMessageOptions getMessageObject = new MQGetMessageOptions();
          MQMessage mqReadMessage = new MQMessage();
          mqReadMessage.write(sResponseMessage.getBytes());

          getMessageObject.waitInterval = 500;
          mqReadMessage.correlationId = mqSendMessage.messageId;
          getMessageObject.matchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
          mqReadMessage.encoding = 546;
          mqReadMessage.characterSet = 1208;

          for (iCounter = iWaitInterval / 500; iCounter > 0; iCounter--)
          {
              try
              {
                  mqLogger.debug("Inside the for loop to read the data from queue - " + sReadQueName);

                  Thread.sleep(500);
                  messageOutputQueue.get(mqReadMessage,getMessageObject);
                  mqLogger.info(sessionId+"Message read from the queue - " + sReadQueName);

                  iMessageLength = mqReadMessage.getDataLength();
                  byte[] btTempMessage = new byte[iMessageLength];
                  mqReadMessage.readFully(btTempMessage,0,iMessageLength);
                  sResponseMessage =new String(btTempMessage);

                  messageOutputQueue.close();
                  mqLogger.debug(sessionId+"Closed the queue - " + sReadQueName);

                  return true;
              }
              catch (MQException mqe)
              {}}
```

Comment: Code, please. How do you read the values?

Comment: I don't see where you write message data into the log. And we should see the section of the log between "Message read from the queue" and "Closed the queue" as accurately as you can get it - text and byte dump in hecadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

The "junk characters" in your log file are very likely the result of logging a text that begins with the arabic letter zain ز that were sent in the XML file encoded as UTF-8 using byte values D8 B2.

These two byte values used as encoding in ISO-8859-1 result in the display of `Ø` and `²`.

(Later on I find `Ø§` or D8 A7, which is an alef ا , then a dal د , a seen س , and so on.)

You can set the encoding of a text file in constructors like OutputStreamWriter or PrintWriter.

To be on the safe side your Java program might log arabic text as a sequence of U-escapes, which avoids all issues of bad encoding interpretation - but you wouldn't see them as arabic characters.

You should check that a text file containing arabic characters in UTF-8 can be inspected correctly on your system.

If (as RealSkeptic comments) reading is the problem, then you should check how the text file is opened. Again, setting the encoding in an InputStreamWriter constructor may be required for interpreting UTF-8 encodings correctly.

Comment: I think the problem is in reading, not in writing, as the OP says the bad values are not just in the log but are used further in the program.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good point, although it's difficult to gain much insight from the text of the Q. Anyway, I've added a few remarks on interpreting/reading the log which very likely contains characters in correct UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I have provided code to read values from host& write to variable. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
      mqReadMessage.write(sResponseMessage.getBytes());
```

and

```
              sResponseMessage =new String(btTempMessage);
```

are the suspect lines of your program.  in both cases, you are using the "default" character set of your jvm.  this may or may not be the rigth character set.  it's *much* better to work with *explicit* character sets when converting between characters and bytes.  e.g. `getBytes(charset)` and `new String(..., charset)`.

which charset to use is up to you and your program's requirements.  UTF-8 is always a great default choice (and frees you from worrying if any text will ever break your choice), but of course your program may require the use of a specific charset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful information. I used code now like strNickName = new String(strNickName.getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")); It is working fine now.